# Leaving a job after 2 weeks for another job in the same company?

Tags: new-job

A little background: I interned for 3 years while in college, however at that point in time, they weren't hiring anyone on full time for that position.

Hi guys, I need some advice. I am a recent college graduate who was pressured by the 'there's no jobs!' sentiment, so I immediately begin fervently applying everywhere I could. The same organization as my internship (a different wing of it) hired me on full-time doing a job I've grown to hate but I definitely needed the money. Cut to two weeks later, that internship I did while in college posted the job.

My question: is it inappropriate for me to potentially switch jobs in the same organization after two weeks? I'm not saying I would 100% get hired, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Voting to close as company specific, they will have rules on internal moves which the random strangers on the internet will not be able to tell you, so speak to HR.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends in the company culture and the relationship between the supervisors or managers of the two teams in concern here. But in general, leaving for greener pastures, even if it is in the same company, after such a short period of time, will not look good, unless you can arrange a lateral move without going through the hiring process. Such as you current supervisor advocating you to this new position. If at all possible. Otherwise, if you apply and this gets heard by your current manager, he or she will admonish you. If you get the other job, it will always cause a riff between two managers. If you don't get the job, you will be the first one to go when there is an organizational shake up and reduction in workforce, because, your current boss will not be trusting you to stick around.

There is no way of sugarcoating this unless the two managers are singing "kumbaya" together :)

Answer (score 1):

Most places wouldn't look favorably on that and many places outright block it requiring X amount of time in your current position before you can apply for other positions. My company just yesterday sent around an email about the current job opportunities and included a reminder that you needed 12 months (18 months for managers+) in your current role before applying for a new one. The reason for this is relatively simple. The company just spent a bunch of money going through the process to higher someone and train them. It takes time for them to become proficient at their role and basically end up making money for the company.